# WIX where can i find WixUi_en-us file?

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix-extension

I have installed Wix 3.5 and i want to customize some dialogs, where can  i find WixUi_en-us file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need download the WiX 3.5 source [from here](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/60102).

Unzip the files. You want to look for UIExtension folder, located in a directory structured something like `src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib`

EDIT: At second glance, I don't see the WiX 3.5 source posted there. Maybe someone else knows. If you just need that strings file though, you can get it by downloading the source code for one of the latest [WiX 3.6 releases](http://wixtoolset.org/releases). Not sure if anything has changed or not as far as that specific file goes.

Comment: Here I can download the sources of 3.5:

http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=wix35